# Android Annotations does not work in Library projects

Tags: java, android, android-library, android-annotations

I am using Android Annotations framework in a library project and it does not compile.

If I remove the code which uses Android Annotations, my project with the library works fine.

When I add any annotation it gives me the error

> Error:Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using  generation
>   folder [project_path/build/generated/source/apt/release])
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':libraryname:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I am using Android Studio 2.3, so I am not using android-apt plugin, instead, I have enabled Annotation Processor from Android Studio settings.

I have also added the annotationProcessorOptions to my library build.gradle file as instructed.

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["library": "true",
"resourcePackageName":"com.android.libraryname"]
            }
        }
```

Also my dependencies looks like this regarding Android Annotations

```
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
compile 'org.androidannotations:rest-spring-api:4.1.0'

annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion
annotationProcessor 'org.androidannotations:rest-spring:4.1.0'
```

Library is normally working fine, and Android Annotations in the client project is also working fine, the problem is caused when I try to use Android Annotations in a library project with Android Studio version 2.3

Is there any way to solve this, I've tried everything I could find but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug which is already fixed. 
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/pull/1975

A new version will be released shortly, until then, you can use the 4.3.0-SNAPSHOT version.
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle#snapshots

Comment: I've tried to use 4.3.0-SNAPSHOT but it gives me the error _Failed to resolve: org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.3.0-SNAPSHOT_ and I have followed the guide as it has been said in here [4.0-SNAPSHOT not found](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/issues/1720), and added Sonatype repository link in my library build.gradle

Comment: Snapshot builds are available now.

Comment: I am still getting the same error unfortunately while trying to build with snapshot version as instructed in the AA wiki